# Can i make a return with messageEmbed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to create a Discord bot. When someone types the `! status` command, the bot should communicate what the server status is. I based my code off of [this bot](https://github.com/skykanin/MC-Status-Discord-Bot).

The only modification I made was so that the bot responds immediately to the `! status` command without asking for the IP.

This is my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

function commandIs(str, msg){
    return msg.content.toLowerCase().startsWith("!" + str);
}

function status(callback) {
    var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ourRequest.open('GET', 'https://mcapi.us/server/status?ip=chocolatada.serveftp.com', true);
      ourRequest.onload = () => {
        var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
        callback(null, checkStatus(ourData));
    };
    ourRequest.onerror = function() {
        console.error(ourRequest.statusText);
    };
    ourRequest.send();
}

function checkStatus(data){
    if(data.online){
        return "Chococraft esta online!, actualmente hay: " + data.players.now + " /" + data.players.max + " " + "La version del server es: " + data.server.name;
    } else {
        return "server offline";
    }
}

client.on('message', message => {
    var args = message.content.split(/[ ]+/);
    if(commandIs("hello", message)){
        message.reply('Hello there');
    }
    if(commandIs("status", message)){
        if(args.length === 2){
            message.channel.sendMessage('Por favor, utiliza `!status`');
        } else if (args.length === 1){
            status((error, result) => {
                if (error) {
                    message.channel.sendMessage("error!");
                    return;
                }
            message.channel.sendMessage(result);
        }, args[1]);
        } else {
            message.channel.sendMessage('You defined too many arguments. Usage: `!status [ip]`');
        }
    }
});

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log("this bot is online")
    console.log('Bot: Hosting ' + `${client.users.size}` + ' users, in ' + `${client.channels.size}` + ' channels of ' + `${client.guilds.size}` + ' guilds.');
    });

client.login('token');
```

Before the return, I put `const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()` and the same online player and server data, and then after the return, I put embed, the console gave me a bad request. (I didn't put all the data I put a test)

```
function checkStatus(data){
    if(data.online){
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .addDescription(data.players)
        return message.channel.send(embed);
    } else {
        return "server offline";
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having right now is a syntax error.

with richembed I tried the following:

```
function checkStatus(data){
    if(data.online){
        const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .addDescription('data.players')
        return message.channel.send(embed);
    } else {
        return "server offline";
    }
}
```

and the console says "TypeError: (intermediate value).addDescription is not a function
    at checkStatus (D:\Documents\Chococraft\Bots\bot status pruebas\Status\bot.js:25:10)"

I tried with .setdescription and the console says "ReferenceError: message is not defined
    at checkStatus (D:\Documents\Chococraft\Bots\bot status pruebas\Status\bot.js:26:9)
    at exports.XMLHttpRequest.ourRequest.onload (D:\Documents\Chococraft\Bots\bot status pruebas\Status\bot.js:14:24)"

```
function checkStatus(data){
    if(data.online){
        const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setDescription('data.players')
        return message.channel.send(embed);
    } else {
        return "server offline";
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting the syntax error?

Comment: @Pepe_Worm TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined

Comment: Could you please tell us what line the error is on so answers can pinpoint which statement is problematic?

Comment: Have you run `npm install discord.js` yet? If you haven't, try doing so and see what happens.

Comment: i tried that and it gave me the error i comment above

Answer (score 0):

You are using MessageEmbed when you are on version 11 of discord, where constructing embeds are made only by using RichEmbed. MessageEmbed is for recieving embeds, and RichEmbed is for making them.

The solution, use RichEmbed() instead of MessageEmbed().

Hope i could help!

Comment: when I tryed whit this, the console says "TypeError: (intermediate value).addDescription is not a function"

Comment: I tried with .setdescription and the console says "ReferenceError: message is not defined at checkStatus (D:\Documents\Chococraft\Bots\bot status pruebas\Status\bot.js:26:9) at exports.XMLHttpRequest.ourRequest.onload (D:\Documents\Chococraft\Bots\bot status pruebas\Status\bot.js:14:24)"

Comment: You might want to also pass the message as a parameter, as the error says, message is not defined in the function. Also, i believe you should learn how to code, not get spoonfed by me or anyone else, so it is my way of helping.